# TWIG how to get the first item from the array

Tags: arrays, twig

I need to get the first item from the field in the twig template. Is there some kind of function?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes, there is, it is called [`first`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/first.html). The rest is copied from the documentation.

> New in version 1.12.2: The first filter was added in Twig 1.12.2.

The first filter returns the first "element" of a sequence, a mapping, or a string:

```
{{ [1, 2, 3, 4]|first }}
{# outputs 1 #}

{{ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }|first }}
{# outputs 1 #}

{{ '1234'|first }}
{# outputs 1 #}
```

It also works with objects implementing the Traversable interface.

Comment: Also works with arrays of objects: `{{ objectArray|first.mymethod }}`

Comment: It is not docummented but `{{ []|first }}` and `{{ {}|first }}` output `FALSE` in twig v2.x

Answer (score 8):

I was looking to get the last element of an array with twig and found this question and found out Twig has a [`last`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/last.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

At **Twig documentation**: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/first.html, you can find the better answer and other related thing also.